# ClipIt keeps synchronizing primary selection with Ctrl+C even after closed/disabled, how to fix?

Tags: clipboard-manager

ClipIt keeps synchronizing primary selection (mouse selection auto copy to clipboard) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (so the primary is overwriting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> one!) even after closed/disabled, how to fix?

I am not being able to work the way I used to, I have no idea what configuration I must undo that ClipIt left behind.
I begin happening after a forced reboot.

Diodon is not working on 16.04, and ClipIt seems good, but needs fix this bug.

The problem persists even after normal reboot (and trying ClipIt options enable/disable too).
Persists also after uninstalling ClipIt, like it have changed some Xorg behavior?

I actually have 3 installed: ClipIt, Parcellite, Diodon. Now Diodon history is working suddenly.

Comment: having a hard time to work on coding on eclipse, the clipboard keeps being overwritten, ohh my :(

Answer (score 2):

ok, I had parcellite, clipit and diodon installed.

I removed clipit and parcellite as diodon history begin working.

even after removed and closed (the indicator), parcellite was still running, I pkill it.

now the problem is solved.

I think we must chose only one to keep installed and running, make sure others arent running (even after uninstalling), and it will work correctly again.